# Android: Service starts after parent activity is finished.

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have the following scheme:

Activity A -which can start Activity B.
Activity B has a background Service it uses which is triggered by an Alarm as follows:

```
alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        serviceSaveSample = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                SaveSampleService.class);
        alarmSaveSample = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                9988766, serviceSaveSample, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (secondsToSample * 1000), secondsToSample * 1000,
                alarmSaveSample);
```

The service implementation:

```
public class SaveSampleService extends Service {    ...

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

          PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, RunActivity.class), 0);


        Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getApplicationContext()).setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText("message").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(startId, notif);
    // some work...
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

the problem is that if i move the app to the background when Activity B is at the top of the stack and the service is running, the service restarts itself after i have closed Activity B explicitly.

i have tried any, if not all flags and still this problem persists. 
tried setting the launchMode to any of the values and still not working.
any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you are not calling `startService` in `onCreate()` of Activity A

Comment: where do you stop your service?

Comment: i stop the alarm when a button is clicked and on onDestroy

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the [`cancel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)) method of `AlarmManager`, and [`stopService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)) in your activity `onStop`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Services` life cycle http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService